# What drove the hotel cook to start attacking students?

Tags: another

In the Another anime most of the students started to kill one another because they wanted to find the dead in order to stop. Even the cook was involved in the killings.

[image]

What's the motive behind her killings? Did she kill the manager and start the fire? Any clue?

Comment: I don't think they necessarily had any actual motives - it seemed more like the curse was causing them to behave erratically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that [lady](http://another.wikia.com/wiki/Keiko_Numata) (her name is Keiko Numata by the way) turned into a killer because of her grandson [Ikuo Takabayashi](http://another.wikia.com/wiki/Ikuo_Takabayashi) who Died boringly by having heart attack. She were emotionally depressed by it and become mentally insane. That why she started killing everyone.

Comment: Who killed the managir and started fire ?

Comment: She killed him and stareted the fire.

Comment: But why did she killed manager ? he has nothing to do with it .

Comment: No reasons at all. She become mentally insane and turned it a psychopathic killer. Even if there is a reasons why she killed her husband in anime they didn't mentioned why she killed him.